# Android Volley library for secure requests

Tags: android, rest, mobile, android-volley, httpurlconnection

I am trying to build my own Android application using Java, and this application will contain sensitive users data like payment information, what is the safest way to implement this for requesting to my database.

I mean when I am using RESTful APIs should I use HttpURLConnection class and you know that need more coding since it should be done on a separated thread , or I can use something like Volley library that have simple coding and work on separated thread ?

**I can guarantee some attacks like SQL Injection wont happen ,but I dont know enough about other possible attacks**